# Passing Key word (vbTab) as argument vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Example text to column function

Try

```
For i As Int32 = 1 To dt1.rows(0)(0).ToString().Split(New Char() {**Separator**}).Length
    Output_Collection.Columns.Add(String.Format("Column {0}", i))

...
```

I wanted to have dynamic Separator (so I can use "." or ",") but also I wanted to use a vb.net key word for {TAB} which is `vbTab`.

Can I use it somehow? When I pass just:

```
Separator = vbTab
```

obviously it's passed as a string

Comment: New Char() {vbTab(0)}

Comment: There may be a better way. I suppose `dt1`is a datatable, `Output_Collection` as well but not sure about what you are trying to achieve. Can you show a data sample and explain the purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answers guys, I think {vbTab(0)} is going to work.

The data sample might be (in .txt file):

```
a   b   c
d   e   f
```

or

```
a.b.c
d.e.f
```

I want to take it as a datatable:

```
col1    col2    col3
a       b       c
d       e       f
```